# Snaps, 20.04 and Persistent USB

Tags: usb, 20.04, live-usb, persistence

I have noticed that with 20.04, casper-rw / writable, Persistent files and partitions are filling up very quickly. Once full the USB does not boot.

Today I had a look and saw that /casper-rw/upper/var/lib/snapd/snaps is 456.5 MB, and I had not even connected to the Internet yet.

This is not good for people who use small utility flash drives.

The snaps files in casper-rw are a duplicate of those already found in Filesystem. I believe on previous versions of Ubuntu only new files and data went into the casper-rw overlay.

I am wondering if this is a Bug that I should report or if this serves a necessary purpose or if there is a simple workaround?

Edit:

I see that in Software and Updates That: "Snap package updates are checked routinely and installed automatically"

This might be a good feature on installed systems but should at least have an opt out option for persistent drives.

Comment: I can't add any knowledge about how to manage snaps in persistent live drives. I don't know where or how their updates are controlled. Maybe an Ubuntu developer will tell you, if you write a bug report about it (like in the case with `fsck.mode=skip`). -- A workaround would be to use a light flavour, Lubuntu or Xubuntu, which are not using snaps by default (at least there is no activated loop device for a snap in [persistent] live drives of Lubuntu or Xubuntu 20.04 LTS).